# how to solve this errorss?egg_info?

Tags: python

Collecting playsound

```
  Using cached playsound-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.7 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\sunka\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
          from setuptools.extension import Extension
        File "C:\Users\sunka\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
        File "C:\Users\sunka\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "C:\Users\sunka\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
          register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
      AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
      [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

```
Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: This is just the entire traceback. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

After searching errors for a long time I came up with this solution; But it depends on setuptools which may be incompatible for different packages

First do;

**pip3 install --upgrade setuptools**

NEXT;

**pip3 install playsound
pip install playsound**